# Finding the image of $y=2x+5$ under the transformation $w=(1+i)z-2$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

> I am trying to find the image of the line $y=2x+5$ under the transformation $w=(1+i)z-2$.

I'm uncertain of how to proceed in questions that do not involve the mapping $w=\frac{1}{z}$. I thought that if I could rewrite the mapping as $w=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi}{4}i}z-2$, this would indicate that the straight line is rotated anticlockwise about the origin by an angle of $\frac{\pi}{4}$, is dilated by $\sqrt{2}$ and translated by 2 units to the right, but I am not confident in these statements.

Is there a general method on how to solve this question? A hint would be very helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it.

Set $z=t+(2t+5)i$. Plug into your transformation. Evaluate. You get a parametric equation for the image of the line.

Comment: Can this method be extended to other transformations? Or only in the case where $w$ is linear?

Comment: @Bell: It will always give you a parametric equation for whatever the image is, but the shape of the parametric equation is not necessarily nice when your $w$ isn't.